# Conflict with understanding a Javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, conflict

There is a Javascript regular expression that I am working with, but that is conflicting with my understanding of how it works.

The expression is this: `/^[0-9]+$/`

So, if I test this regular expression on, say the value of a textbox, what I understand is that it will check whether the value starts with at least one digit, and ends with at least one digit. However, what is happening is that the test is being successful only when the whole value is being numeric. If I place an alphabet in between, which I understand should make the test successful, the latter is failing.

Can anyone clarify me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, it means a series of 1 or more digits from the start to the end.

```
^[0-9].+[0-9]$
```

would give your understanding of what its doing.

Comment: Ok, so it doesn't check for digits at the start and at the end individually, but rather 'from the start to the end'?

Comment: no, it means at the start of the line, there should be 1 or more numeric characters and then there should be the end of the line

Answer (score 1):

Your expression `/^[0-9]+$/` says...

- `^`  says "start at the beginning of the string"
- `[0-9]` says "the matching string must next contain a number"
- `+` says, "the number may repeat any number of times, but must be there at least once"
- `$` says, "the string must then end"

Since you didn't specify that there could be characters -or anything - in the middle, your regex won't match it.  If you wanted "starts with a number and ends with a number" try...

`/^[0-9](.*[0-9])?$/` which says

- `^` start at the beginning of the string
- `(` start a group - but ignore this for now... it'll become apparent later
- `[0-9]` followed by a number
- `.` followed by any character
- `*` and let that "any character" specified immediately prior repeat zero or more times
- `[0-9]` followed by a number
- `)?` but allow the "any character followed by a number" to exist or not exist.  This allows us to have exactly one number as a matching string.
- $ and end the string

Or you could use `/^[0-9]([0-9a-zA-Z]*[0-9])?$/` if you want to restrict to numbers and letters